# Is myisam table created in case sensitive perform better than case-insensitive?

Tags: mysql, performance, collation, myisam

let's said table A create with definition `keyword varchar(255) collate latin1_general_cs` with index create on it

table B create with definition `keyword varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci`,

both insert same set of data

and perform the same set of query 
`select * from my_table where keyword='apple'`

will query to table A faster than table B?

any benchmark results can show the differences (or there is no difference at all)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing is the only way to be sure, but being case *insensitive* (ci) means matching more records so my inclination is that case sensitive is better performing.

Comment: ponies - somehow in the same thought, however cs giving some headache where u need to do `lower` this and that for comparison or better suggestion that `lower` ?

Comment: @ajreal: Full Text Search (FTS) might help, because LOWER/etc will render an index useless.  You can also temporarily force case in/sensitive using the `COLLATE` notation in queries.  There's rarely a silver bullet - you have to review the options & be aware of shortcomings.

Comment: testing seems to the only way, will pump in some test data to really test it out